# Какие значения хранит char

Tags: c++, char, символы

У меня возник вопрос по поводу значений которые может хранить [char](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF#:%7E:text=Char%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD,%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D1%82%200%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20255.). Википедия говорит о том, что:
Если char определён как signed (знаковый), то его диапазон значений составляет от −128 до 127. И теперь я хочу сделать вывод всех символов, которые может хранить `char`.

```
for (int i = -128; i < 128; i++)
{
    cout << (char)i << ' ';
}
```

На вывод получаю:

```
А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п ░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛ ┐ └ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼ ╞ ╟ ╚ ╔ ╩ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬ ╧ ╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я Ё ё Є є Ї ї Ў ў ° ∙ · √ № ¤ ■    ☺ ☻ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠
 ♫ ☼ ► ◄ ↕ ‼ ¶ § ▬ ↨ ↑ ↓ → ∟↔▲▼ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ ⌂
```

Но если я пишу вот такой код:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    cout << (char)i << ' ';
}
```

Вывод:

```
 ☺ ☻ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠
 ♫ ☼ ► ◄ ↕ ‼ ¶ § ▬ ↨ ↑ ↓ → ∟↔▲▼ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~ ⌂ А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ы Ь Э Ю Я а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п ░ ▒ ▓ │ ┤ ╡ ╢ ╖ ╕ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╜ ╛ ┐ └ ┴ ┬ ├ ─ ┼ ╞ ╟ ╚ ╔ ╩ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬ ╧ ╨ ╤ ╥ ╙ ╘ ╒ ╓ ╫ ╪ ┘ ┌ █ ▄ ▌ ▐ ▀ р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я Ё ё Є є Ї ї Ў ў ° ∙ · √ № ¤ ■
```

Результаты вывода примерно одинаковые, разве что немного отличается порядок, почему так? Но это еще не самое главное: если диапазон значений от -128 до 127 (включительно), то почему тогда я могу записать число 256 для `signed char`. Объясните мне пожалуйста)

Comment: Есть такая вещь - *приведение типов*...

Comment: @Harry, я что-то совсем запутался, я понял что я допустил глупую ошибку, но не понял какую конкретно. не могли бы вы конкретно сказать в чём проблема, а то я уже что-то совсем:(

Comment: Реально берется младший байт int-а (т.е. тоже самое, что i & 0xff). Т.е. никакой ошибки в обеих случаях нет, перебираете все 256 разных значений младшего байта (0 ... 255), начиная с разных точек. Попадая в окошко вывода этот байт (unsigned, естественно) используется как индекс в таблице глифов (начертаний символов). Видно, что вы используете кодировку cp866 (т.е. скорее всего винда (значит **у вас signed char**, диапазон значений в крестах **-128 ... 127**) ,  а эмулятор -- программа cmd)   /  Кстати,  256  не попадет (станет нулем).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значение любого целочисленного типа может быть преобразовано в значение любого другого целочисленного типа. Алгоритм преобразования следующий ([conv.integral](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral)):

- Если целевой тип `bool`, то нулевое значение преобразуется в `false`, а любое ненулевое значение преобразуется в `true`.
- Если исходный тип `bool`, то значение `false` преобразуется в `0`, а значение `true` преобразуется в `1`.
- В противном случае, результатом будет значение целевого типа, [сравнимое по модулю](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E) (*congruent modulo*) `2^N` с исходным значением, где `N` — это ширина (*width*) целевого типа (в целевом типе такое значение единственно).

Последний пункт говорит, что преобразования из одного целочисленного типа в другой выполняются по правилам [модулярной арифметики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). В общем-то статья на Википедии довольно подробно описывает её особенности, но если ранее вы с ней не сталкивались, то полагаю, тут не помешает менее формальное объяснение.

Ширина (width) целочисленного типа — это количество битов, используемых для представления значения данным целочисленным типом (включая знаковый бит). Ширина непосредственным образом определяет *диапазон значений* (*range of representable values*) представимых некоторым целочисленным типом. Если ширина целочисленного типа равна `N`, то для беззнакового типа диапазон равен `[0; 2^N - 1]`, а для знакового типа диапазон равен `[-2^(N-1); 2^(N-1) - 1]`.

Для того, чтобы понять, каков всё-таки будет конечный результат преобразования, можно рассуждать следующим образом (*Представленное объяснение приведено сугубо с целью объяснения модулярной арифметики. Компилятор не обязан действовать буквально так, как описано ниже.*):

- Если исходное значение представимо целевым типом, то исходное значение не изменится при преобразовании.
- Если исходное значение больше максимального значения, представимого целевым типом, то из исходного значения следует вычитать величину `2^N` (`N` — ширина целевого типа) до тех пор, пока оно не станет представимо целевым типом. Получившееся значение и будет результатом преобразования.
- Если исходное значение меньше минимального значения, представимого целевым типом, то к исходному значению следует прибавлять величину `2^N` (`N` — ширина целевого типа) до тех пор, пока оно не станет представимо целевым типом. Получившееся значение и будет результатом преобразования.

Итак, пусть тип `char` знаковый, и его ширина равна `8` (`N == 8`), тогда диапазон его значений `[-2^(8-1); 2^(8-1) - 1] == [-128; 127]`, и `2^N == 2^8 == 256`. Вот некоторые результаты преобразований в соответствии с описанными правилами:

```
(char)127 => 127

(char)128 => 128 - 256 == -128
(char)129 => 129 - 256 == -127
(char)255 => 255 - 256 == -1

(char)256 => 256 - 256 ==  0
(char)257 => 257 - 256 ==  1
(char)383 => 383 - 256 ==  127

(char)384 => 384 - 256 * 2 == -128

(char)(2^32 - 1) => (2^32 - 1) - 256 * 2^24 == -1

(char)-129 => -129 + 256 ==  127
(char)-130 => -130 + 256 ==  126
```

Тестовая программа [для проверки](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87affb0e696b181e):

```
long long arr[] = {
    127,
    128, 129, 255,
    256, 257, 383,
    384,
    4'294'967'295LL, //2^32 - 1
    -129,
    -130
};

for (long long val: arr) {
    auto res = (char)val;
    cout << (int)res << endl;
}
```

Если учитывать, что для представления целых числе используется [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (*two’s complement*), то алгоритм преобразования можно описать так.

Пусть ширина целевого типа равна `N`, а ширина исходного типа равна `K`, тогда

- если `N <= K`, то тогда младшие `N` бит исходного значения будут в точности кодировать значение целевого типа.
- если `N > K` и исходное значение неотрицательно, то дополняем старшие биты исходного значения нулями так, чтобы итоговое количество бит стало равно `N`. Получившаяся последовательность бит кодирует значение целевого типа.
- если `N > K` и исходное значение отрицательно, то дополняем старшие биты исходного значения единицами так, чтобы итоговое количество бит стало равно `N`. Получившаяся последовательность бит кодирует значение целевого типа.

Итак, пусть ширина типа `unsigned short` равна шестнадцати битам, а типа `char` равна восьми битам (и он знаковый).

Преобразуем значение `3968` типа `unsigned short` в значение типа `char`.

```
(unsigned short)3968 == 00001111 10000000
```

Младшие восемь бит кодируют значение целевого типа:

```
10000000 == (char)-128.
```

Преобразуем значение `1` типа `char` в значение типа `unsigned short`.

```
(char)1 == 00000001
```

Т.к. исходное значение неотрицательно, то дополняем старшие биты нулями до необходимого размера.

```
00000001 => 00000000 00000001 == (unsigned short)1
```

Преобразуем значение `-1` типа `char` в значение типа `unsigned short`.

```
(char)-1 == 11111111
```

Т.к. исходное значение отрицательно, то дополняем старшие биты единицами до необходимого размера.

```
11111111 => 11111111 11111111 == (unsigned short)65535
```

---

Написанное выше справедливо начиная с C++20. В более ранних версиях стандарта есть некоторые отличия.

- Если целевой тип *знаковый*, и исходное значение не представимо целевым типом, то результат преобразования определяется реализацией (*implementation-defined*). (Например, такая безобидная на вид конструкция `(char)128`, теоретически, запросто могла бы аварийно завершить работу программы, т.к. значение `128` не представимо восьмибитным знаковым типом `char`. Но на практике обычно ничего такого не происходило, и преобразование происходило по правилам модулярной арифметики.)
- Для представления целочисленных типов не требуется использовать дополнительный код. Следовательно, приведённое выше описание, основанное на дополнительном коде, не актуально. Шансы наткнуться на такой компилятор на практике исчезающе малы.
- Хоть минимальная ширина типа `char` равна восьми, стандарт не гарантировал, что значение `-128` представимо знаковым типом `char`. В дополнительном коде битовый паттерн `10000000` мог использоваться для кодирования особого значения *trap representation*. Попытка чтения такого значения приводит к неопределённому поведению. Но опять же, попробуй найди такой компилятор.

Answer (score 5):

Отрицательные числа в архитектуре IBM PC представляются в так называемом дополнительном коде. Т.е., если мы имеем разрядность `n`, то некоторое отрицательное число `-k` в знаковой трактовке (signed) соответствует числу `2^n-k` в беззнаковой трактовке (unsigned). Так, для типа `char` имеем разрядность `n==8`. Тогда отрицательное число `-k` соответствуют беззнаковому `256-k`. Например, `-1` для `signed char` - это `256-1 == 255` для `unsigned char`. А знаковое `-128`  - это беззнаковое `256-128 == 128`. Таким образом, если мы будем отсчитывать `char` со знаком от `0` по возрастанию, то получим последовательность: `0, 1, 2,... 126, 127`, а после 127 мы получим сразу `-128` (это называется знаковым переполнением разрядной сетки), и последовательность продолжится (в скобках укажу беззнаковую трактовку): `-127 (129) , -126 (130),... -2 (254), -1 (255), 0`.

По-этому перебор всех `char` от -128 до +127 равносилен перебору всех `unsigned char` сначала от 128 до 255, а затем от 0 до 127 - это ваш первый цикл, в то время как второй цикл перебирает символы уже в нормальном порядке от 0 до 255.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но есть вопрос, каким образом компьютер отличит от 255(256-k), которое отрицательное от 255, которое положительное?

Comment: @n 1 k z z z Для работы с бесзнаковыми и знаковыми числами существуют свои наборы машинных инструкций. Например, команды ассемблера mul и div, соответственно, умножают и делят числа без знака, а если надо разделить или перемножить числа со знаком, применяются инструкции imul и idiv. Компилятор генерирует соответствующий машинный код, руководствуясь информацией о типах переменных. Примерно так, если вкратце.

Comment: В общем случае он их никак и не отличает.